# Deserialize JSON to anonymous object in asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net-5

I have a XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<RESPONSE>
    <SINGLE>
        <KEY name="grades">
            <MULTIPLE>
                <SINGLE>
                    <KEY name="courseid">
                        <VALUE>3</VALUE>
                    </KEY>
                    <KEY name="grade">
                        <VALUE>40.00</VALUE>
                    </KEY>
                    <KEY name="rawgrade">
                        <VALUE>40.00000</VALUE>
                    </KEY>
                    <KEY name="rank">
                        <VALUE null="null"/>
                    </KEY>
                </SINGLE>
            </MULTIPLE>
        </KEY>
        <KEY name="warnings">
            <MULTIPLE></MULTIPLE>
        </KEY>
    </SINGLE>
</RESPONSE>
```

I have converted it to JSON string like with below

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

But I need to assign my JSON into object of the below class type

```
public class Grades
{
    public string Courseid { get; set; }
    public string Grade{ get; set; }
    public string Rawgrade{ get; set; }
    public string Rank{ get; set; }
}
```

So that, I can access or assign my values into

```
Grade mygrade;
```

or later `mygrade.Courseid`

and now it looks like this:

```
{
  "?xml": {
    "@version": "1.0",
    "@encoding": "UTF-8"
  },
  "RESPONSE": {
    "SINGLE": {
      "KEY": [
        {
          "@name": "grades",
          "MULTIPLE": {
            "SINGLE": {
              "KEY": [
                {
                  "@name": "courseid",
                  "VALUE": "3"
                },
                {
                  "@name": "grade",
                  "VALUE": "40.00"
                },
                {
                  "@name": "rawgrade",
                  "VALUE": "40.00000"
                },
                {
                  "@name": "rank",
                  "VALUE": {
                    "@null": "null"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "@name": "warnings",
          "MULTIPLE": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But I need the JSON like the following

```
{
  "courseid" : "3",
  "grade": "40.00",
  "rawgrade": "40.00000",
  "rank": "null"
}
```

How can I assign properly my json to the above class format `Grades`? Can anyone please help me? I am new to ASP.NET Core.

Comment: use dyanmic object

Comment: Can you detail what make this question unique to ASP.NET Core? Are you looking to do this as a request is received from the client, so that the controller method receives the final object?

Comment: You cannot convert XML to JSON - at least not the way you want it to. You have to de-serialize the xml to an object and then serialize that to JSON. Apart from this why should your `Repsonse`-object be some anonymous class?

Comment: @Llama yes added to question, please have a look

Comment: How are you receiving this object exactly?

Comment: @Llama I am consuming a 3rd party api which return the above XML and I have converted that into JSON. Now my goal is to assign the json into the mentioned class

Comment: In that case I'll remove your ASP.NET-related tags. I was trying to find how ASP.NET Core (since it was tagged) was related to your question, so I assumed you were receiving the XML data via _your_ ASP.NET Core API.

Comment: I would use LinqToXml and load the data into the object directly from XML. Without intermediate Json.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Thanks for your input. I tried Krishna Muppalla's solution and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your input xml and output json, you cannot directly convert to JSON. Here is one approach using `LINQ` to get desired object and Serialize using `JsonConvert`

```
var strFile = File.ReadAllText("XMLFile1.xml");

var grades = xdoc.Descendants("KEY")
                 .Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "grades")
                 .Descendants("SINGLE")
                 .Select(y => new Grades
                  {
                        Courseid = y.Descendants("KEY").Where(z => z.Attribute("name").Value == "courseid").Select(a => a.Element("VALUE").Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        Grade = y.Descendants("KEY").Where(z => z.Attribute("name").Value == "grade").Select(a => a.Element("VALUE").Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        Rawgrade = y.Descendants("KEY").Where(z => z.Attribute("name").Value == "rawgrade").Select(a => a.Element("VALUE").Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                        Rank = y.Descendants("KEY").Where(z => z.Attribute("name").Value == "rank").Select(a => a.Element("VALUE").Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                  });
                    
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(grades));
```

Comment: please have a look to my updated question

Comment: @ShuvoBarua I have updated the post. Hope this helps